# DataPower - Azure Service Bus Integration

Tags: azureservicebus, ibm-datapower

I am trying to post messages to Azure service bus from DataPower using http protocol. How should I pass the credentials since I am getting an unauthorized error 401.

Please help since I got stuck here

Thanks

Comment: from [wikipedia on 401 status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) "The response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource" , what does that response header field "WWW-Authenticate" contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Below is how I achieve SAS authentication token.

1. Generate SAS token in IIB using a Java module which requires 4 parameters:

   a. Resource URI of Azure Service Bus
   b. Key
   c. Key Name
   d. Expiry in seconds.
2. Set the SAS token in MQRFH2 header and send to DataPower
3. Extract SAS token and set as Authorization header for HTTP POST request in DataPower using the below xslt.

```
<xsl:variable name="entries" select="dp:request-header('MQRFH2')" />
<xsl:variable name="header" select="dp:parse($entries)" />
<xsl:variable name="SAS">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$header//usr//SAS">
<xsl:value-of select="$header//usr//SAS" />
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="false()" />
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<dp:set-http-request-header name="'Authorization'" value="$SAS"/>
```

Comment: There is no XSLT... :o

Comment: I have added it in the previous post but its not displaying in the forum.
 I have pasted again below<xsl:variable name="entries" select="dp:request-header('MQRFH2')" />
    <xsl:variable name="header" select="dp:parse($entries)" />
    <xsl:variable name="SAS">
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$header//usr//SAS">
    <xsl:value-of select="$header//usr//SAS" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="false()" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <dp:set-http-request-header name="'Authorization'" value="$SAS"/>

Comment: abhi, there are three ways to fix the XSLT not showing up, if you click edit  you can see that I just added a HTML comment `<!>` on a empty line above the content which was already spaced in for spaces to cause it to be a code block..  It seems to be that sometimes content following a numbered list is not formatted as expected, I have never seen it just disappear as in this case, but have had other similar issues in the past.  The other ways to fix it are 1. to double up the indent to 8 spaces, 2. use four ```` on a line by itself above and below the block of XSLT.  I also fixed your a b c d.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you are using `Shared Access Signatures` (SAS) or `Access Control Service` (ACS) for you Service Bus.

I'd recommend to use SAS!

Unfortunately the Azure Node.js SDK has a lot of fs (file system) calls which DataPower GatewayScript can't handle so we can't use that.

This is a snippet I found somewhere that I have used for SAS as GatewayScript to create the headers:

```js
'use strict';

var crypto = require('crypto');

// ServiceBus parameters
var namespace = '<Your-ServiceBus-Namespace>';
var queue ='<Your-Queue>';
var AccessKeyName = '<Your-AccessKey-Name>';
var AccessKey = '<Your-AccessKey>';


// Full ServiceBus Queue publisher URI
var ServiceBusUri = 'https://' + namespace + '.servicebus.windows.net' + '/' + queue;
 
function createSASToken(uri, keyName, key)
{
    //Token expires in December
    var expiry = '1417774602';
    var crypto = require('crypto');

    var signedString = encodeURIComponent(uri) + '\n' + expiry;
    var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key);
    hmac.update(signedString);
    var signature = hmac.digest('base64');
    var token = 'SharedAccessSignature sr=' + encodeURIComponent(uri) + '&sig=' + encodeURIComponent(signature) + '&se=' + expiry + '&skn=' + keyName;
 
    return token;
}
 
var SASToken = createSASToken(ServiceBusUri, AccessKeyName, AccessKey)
console.log(SASToken);

var options = {
        hostname: namespace + '.' + 'servicebus.Windows.net',
        port: 443,
        path: '/' + queue + '/messages',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': SASToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8',
        }
    };

// GatewayScript url-open() goes here...

// End
```

I have just pulled out the code from another project so you need to add some handlers and the GatewayScript framework on it...

Comment: I have generated SAS token and I am posting the request from DataPower to Azure Service Bus after setting the SAS token as the Authorization header value. But I am still getting a 401 error saying i am unauthorized. Is there anyway to see the SAS token received on Azure Service Bus

Comment: By enabling the DataPower Probe in your service (MPGW?) you can see the sent headers if you chose the final step and look in the Headers tab. That will show you what is sent to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

As this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-authentication-and-authorization) mentioned about Service Bus authentication and authorization:

> Applications can authenticate to Azure Service Bus using either **Shared Access Signature (SAS) authentication**, or through **Azure Active Directory Access Control** (also known as Access Control Service or ACS).
>
> **SAS** is recommended over ACS, as it **provides a simple, flexible, and easy-to-use authentication scheme for Service Bus**. Applications can use SAS in scenarios in which they do not need to manage the notion of an authorized "user."

**1) Shared Access Signature**

The token is in the following format:

`SharedAccessSignature sig=<signature-string>&se=<expiry>&skn=<keyName>&sr=<URL-encoded-resourceURI>`

Use the Shared Access Signature (at HTTP level) for [sending message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue):

```html
POST http{s}://<yournamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<path>/messages
Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3A%2F%2F<yournamespace>.servicebus.windows.net%2F<path>&sig=<your-signature>&se=1438205742&skn=KeyName
ContentType: application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8
```

For more details, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas) for generating the SAS token based on your development language.

**2) Access Control Service (ACS)**

you must create the namespace using the [New-AzureSBNamespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/servicemanagement/azure.compute/v1.6.1/New-AzureSBNamespace) PowerShell cmdlet as follows:

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2014/08/29/service-bus-namespace-creation-on-portal-no-longer-has-acs-connection-string/).

Use ACS for sending message:

```html
POST http{s}://<yournamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<path>/messages
Authorization: WRAP access_token={swt}
ContentType: application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8
```

**Construct a SWT token**

[image]

For more details about getting a SWT token, you could refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willpe/2011/05/11/getting-access-control-service-tokens-via-http/) and this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh674475.aspx) about how to request a Token from ACS.